# How to fix: FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/PollingApp] but context failed to start error in Netbeans/Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, context.xml

I'm trying to implement my voting app to tomcat web server and I changed my context.xml file BUT to no avail, so what's the default code for context.xml? I tried to delete the file and restart NetBeans but also the same problem occurred... Here's the output of my context.xml error:

compile-jsps:
Incrementally de

```
ploying http://localhost:8080/PollingApp
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8080/PollingApp
Incrementally redeploying http://localhost:8080/PollingApp
Deploy is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2F0s%2Fy4my3bp16s98bg06fngwr4t40000gn%2FT%2Fcontext1962805577261409935.xml&path=/PollingApp
FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/PollingApp] but context failed to start
/Users/fabiovreede/NetBeansProjects/PollingApp/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

So what should I do??

This is for my school, I'm working on a web application project for a survey poll app... I'm working with Apache Tomcat 9, MySQL 8.0.15 and Netbeans 8.2 with JSP and after changing META-INF folder with context.xml, adding Resources method, I got this error about not being able to deploy to Tomcat.

Edit added exception stack trace:

```
29-Mar-2019 19:26:05.134 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
29-Mar-2019 19:26:05.134 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/PollingApp] startup failed due to previous errors
29-Mar-2019 19:26:05.135 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat v9.0.17/conf/Catalina/localhost/PollingApp.xml] has finished in [3,870] ms
29-Mar-2019 19:26:05.135 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat v9.0.17/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
29-Mar-2019 19:26:05.183 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [] in deployment descriptor [/usr/local/tomcat v9.0.17/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has been ignored
29-Mar-2019 19:26:05.186 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal Failed to read manifest from [/Users/USERNAME/NetBeansProjects/PollingApp/build/web/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF]
  java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:410)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal(DirResourceSet.java:272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1832)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:634)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

Comment: Please follow the advice and `See the server log for details.`. Then edit your question to share your findings.

Comment: And where can I find "server log" you mentioned? Sorry, I'm quite new on this kind of thing...

Comment: They are in [apacheTomcatBaseDir]/logs/catalina.log

Comment: Oh well, I'm going to edit my post with the error log... I don't know where it's wrong though, I hope you could help me through...

Comment: The most important stuff are full exception stack traces.

Comment: See the update, I wonder if this is good enough??? :P

Comment: I fear you missed the importent part: the exception stack trace that happened **before** the log entries presented have been writen: `Context [/PollingApp] startup failed due to previous errors` This indicates there was an exception before. Depending on your log level and application bootstrap complexity, the exception can be place many lines above this indication. But it's likly the correct logfile.

Comment: Okay, I edited it... Took a long time to find them though.

Comment: How does the `/Users/USERNAME/NetBeansProjects/PollingApp/build/web/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` look like? Seemes there is an issue.

Comment: There's no MANIFEST.MF file, how strange...

Comment: I figured it out, the problem was within Web.xml inside WEB-INF folder... I had to change pathname :P